# Function composition in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I wanted to implement a version of [rambda's compose](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) function in python. I also implemented some examples to show its working. However, I would like the community's input on my code:

These are the methods I use for testing

```
from functools import reduce, partial
import random
import math


def calcMean(iterable):
    return sum(iterable) / len(iterable)


def formatMean(mean):
    return round(float(mean), 2)


def adder(val, value):
    return val + value


def multiplier(val, value):
    return val * value


def isEven(val):
    return val % 2 == 0
```

The actual compose function

```
def compose(*fargs):
    def inner(arg):
        if not arg:
            raise ValueError("Invalid argument")
        if not all([callable(f) for f in fargs]):
            raise TypeError("Function is not callable")
        return reduce(lambda arg, func: func(arg), fargs, arg)
    return inner
```

The first exercise is something I came up with. In it I populate a list of length 10000 with random numbers from 0 to 10000, find the mean, round it to 2 decimal places, add 1 to it , then floor it and finally print out whether it is even or not.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ex1
    rand_range = [random.randint(0, 10000) for x in range(0, 10000)]

    isRandIntEven = compose(calcMean, formatMean,
                            partial(adder, value=1), math.floor.__call__, isEven)

    print(isRandIntEven(rand_range))
```

The second exercise is taken from [rambda's compose](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) page. I tried to see if I could replicate the example (theirs is much more elegant)

```
    # Ex2
    classyGreeting = lambda firstName, lastName: "The name's " + \
        lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + lastName
    yellGreeting = compose(partial(
    classyGreeting, "James".upper()), str.upper.__call__)

    print(yellGreeting("Bond"))
```

The last example is also taken from [rambda's compose](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) page

```
# Ex3
    print(compose(
        partial(multiplier, value=2),
        partial(adder, value=1),
        math.fabs)(-4))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggestions for `compose`:

```
def compose(*fargs):
    def inner(arg):
        if not arg:
            raise ValueError("Invalid argument")
        if not all([callable(f) for f in fargs]):
            raise TypeError("Function is not callable")
        return reduce(lambda arg, func: func(arg), fargs, arg)
    return inner
```

1. `if not arg`: What's wrong with arg being falsey? Perhaps that's an acceptable input. Input validation should be designated to the functions being composed, which can raise their own errors.
2. `if not all([callable(f) ...`: This line should be before `def inner(args)`. It should be a single-time input validation to ensure that all given inputs in `fargs` are callable. Currently, it checks needless amounts of times (each `inner` call) and does not check immediately.
3. `if not all([callable(f) ...`: You can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension for this, slightly improving readability.

If both of these suggestions are implemented, your `compose` would look like:

```
def compose(*fargs):
    if not all(callable(f) for f in fargs):
        raise TypeError("Function is not callable")
    def inner(arg):
        return reduce(lambda arg, func: func(arg), fargs, arg)
    return inner
```

Please tell me if I have misunderstood your code.

Comment: Yeah I understand your point with  the functions that are being composed handling the case of arg being falsy. Oh didn't know writing `all()` like `all(callable(f) ....` turns it into a generator.  Thanks for your input

Comment: @CasualCoder3 It doesn't turn the result of `all(...` into a generator, if that's what you mean. The "actual" call is `all( (callable(f) for f in fargs) )`, which passes the generator produces by `(callable(f) for f in fargs)` into `all` and evaluates to a boolean. (I call it the "actual" call because it explicitly shows the generator expression by including its ()'s. Python allows for omitting of ()'s around a generator expression if it's the sole argument to a function).